# Bad credentials Spring boot when using withDefaultPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        userDetailsManager.createUser(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build()
                );
        userDetailsManager.createUser(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build());
        return userDetailsManager;
    }
}
```

I used admin & password to login and it failed. I also used user & password and it failed. The error I got was bad credentials. Any help with understanding the issue and how to fix it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        userDetailsManager.createUser(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build()
                );
        userDetailsManager.createUser(
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build());
        return userDetailsManager;
    }
}
```

Finally figured out the problem. I should have added @Configuration and @EnableMethodSecurity before creating the class.